# Participant Name and Attendance in the same row in Google form

Tags: google-forms

I would like to create a Google form which can give me the following sort of response in Excel Sheet.

```
Student Name    4-Jun
XYZ                 P
```

We are using this kind of sheet to mark attendance. All I was able to create from a Google form was

```
Timestamp               XYZ 
7/6/2013 6:05:19    Present
```

Thus instead of having student names as columns, we would like to have them as rows and mark their attendance by dates as columns. Let me know if there is a way to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the feature is available directly, but once you have the final spreadsheet, you can use the TRANSPOSE function to rotate the results onto a new worksheet. Details are [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/9oqORl12F3g).